# How to force bookdown to render document with xelatex engine instead of pdflatex?

Tags: r, bookdown, xelatex

I use bookdown to render html books. How can render the same book using LaTeX enging xelatex instead of pdflatex?

This is the main code I use:

```
bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', output_file='mybook.pdf','bookdown::pdf_book')
```

It keeps on saying `! Sorry, but C:\PROGRA~1\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.`. Because when rendering other kinds of pdf documents I use xelatex as an enging, I know it should be available in my system. How can I force bookdown to use xelatex?

[Here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/201) this answer seemed to be asked before, but I have no idea how to use the mentioned solution: `pandoc_options(args = c("--latex-engine", "xelatex"))`.

When I do something like this:

```
bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', output_file='mybook.pdf','bookdown::pdf_book',pandoc_options(latex_engine = 'xelatex'))
```

There is an error: `Error in pandoc_options(latex_engine = "xelatex") :  argument "to" is missing, with no default`

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: As detailed [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/2.1/topics/pandoc_options), `pandoc_options` has an argument called `to` (I guess it is the name of the output but I may be wrong). You didn't specify this argument, hence the error. You can also specify the `latex_engine` in the YAML, as explained [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-variables.html)

Comment: thanks for your response. I already tried that, but bookdown keeps on wanting to  use pdflatex.

Comment: Did you check that the indentation was good in YAML? I was recently surprised with some YAML options not taken into account because indentation was bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to insert this into `_output.yml` general configuration file (for `bookdown`, as seen in the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/publishers.html)):

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  latex_engine: xelatex
```

This usually worked in my cases.

If you want to use `pandoc_options()`, you'll probably have to pass `to` argument as well (I haven't tried this):

```
bookdown::render_book(
  'index.Rmd',
  output_file = 'mybook.pdf',
  'bookdown::pdf_book',
  pandoc_options(
    to = "pdf",
    latex_engine = "xelatex"
  )
)
```

Comment: yes, that one worked. Thanks! I overlooked (somehow) the fact that I had to add `bookdown::`

Comment: My machine is still using pdftex, any suggestion?